# How garbage collector will handle if all objects are in use

Tags: java, .net, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have studied that, GC will collect the unused memory reference using Mark and Sweep algorithm.

Let's assume a case like,

You have created a lot of objects and assigned to a variable, and you are using those variables in
Case 1. Frequent interval 
Case 2. Infrequent interval

Let's take these objects types are

Case 1: all managed resource only. 
Case 2: all unmanaged resource only. 
Case 3: Mix of both managed and unmanaged resource.

And also let's assume the program is having enough logic for the Destructor and Dispose to clear the unmanaged resource.

The threshold limit is reached and it has no more physical memory.

How .Net GC will deal these 2 cases (Both interval and type of object case)?

I believe irrespective of language (ex:.Net, Java) they have a way to handle this case.

Could someone help me to understand this one.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not “irrespective of language” as the terms you are using, like “managed resource”, “unmanaged resource”, “Destructor, and Dispose” have no meaning in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> I have studied that, GC will collect the unused memory reference using Mark and Sweep algorithm.

(There are other algorithms ... and Java normally uses some kind of generational algorithm rather than mark-sweep.)

> The threshold limit is reached and it has no more physical memory.
>
> How .Net GC will deal these 2 cases

In the Java case, if the objects are all still (strongly) reachable, then ultimately a request to create an object will throw an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.  That will typically cause the application to crash.

Complications:

- If the application uses soft references, then the GC will cause some or all of these references to be broken to try to free up some heap space.
- The application could catch the OOME further up the stack.  That could cause some variables to go out of scope, or the OOME handler could take steps to `null` variables, etcetera.  If enough objects become unreachable, the application may be able to continue.

---

Note: pure Java doesn't make a distinction between managed and unmanaged resources.  In the .NET sense, all Java objects are managed.

A Java application *could* call a native code library that allocated stuff in the native heap.  If that happens, the GC is not involved in the allocation, and cannot clean up.  Cleanup would be the library's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector cannot free objects that are in use. If you run out of memory, you run out of memory; if infinite memory were possible then [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) in Java (and [`System.OutOfMemoryException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET) would not exist and [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) would not crash programs.